# the content of my uitableviewCell doen't show up?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I don't know why the content of my cell doen't show up in my tableview controller even when I check if there is values with NSLog I find them but don't show up !! 
 
I've created my cell programatically also my views 

those are files 
 **cell.h** :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ContactTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *contactImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *fullNameLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *phoneNumberLabel;
@end
```

**cell.m**

```
#import "ContactTableViewCell.h"
#import <Masonry.h>

@interface ContactTableViewCell ()

@end

@implementation ContactTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        self.fullNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [self.fullNameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [self.fullNameLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        [self.fullNameLabel setHidden:NO];
        self.fullNameLabel.text =@"test";
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.fullNameLabel];

        // Add this label to the button
        self.phoneNumberLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [self.phoneNumberLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
        [self.phoneNumberLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [self.phoneNumberLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_fullNameLabel];

        [self.phoneNumberLabel setHidden:NO];
    }
    return self;
}

// tell UIKit that you are using AutoLayout
+ (BOOL)requiresConstraintBasedLayout {
    return YES;
}

-(void)updateViewConstraints{

    [_fullNameLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_top);
        make.right.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_right);
        make.left.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_left);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_bottom);
    }];

    [self updateConstraints];
}

@end
```

**uitableview.h**

```
    @interface ContactsTableView : UITableView
    - (instancetype) initWithContent : (NSArray *)  content;
    @end
```

**UitableView.m**

```
    #import "ContactsTableView.h"
#import "ContactTableViewCell.h"

@interface ContactsTableView () <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *content;

@end

@implementation ContactsTableView

- (instancetype) initWithContent : (NSArray *)  content {
    self = [super initWithFrame:self.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.delegate = self;
    self.dataSource = self;
    self.content = content;
    return self;

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _content.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    ContactTableViewCell *cell = (ContactTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[ContactTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:249.0/255 green:237.0/255 blue:224.0/255 alpha:1.0];
    cell.fullNameLabel.text =  self.content[indexPath.row];
    cell.phoneNumberLabel.text = self.content[indexPath.row];
    [cell updateConstraints];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    NSLog(@"title of cell %ld", indexPath.row);
}

@end
```

this is the background of cell when I put it to red : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYl10.png)

Comment: What do you see when you step through in debug? Is `initWithStyle` actually being called? If so, are the subviews really being added to the cell's contentView? If so, are the constraints being set correctly? Need a little more detail than "they don't show up"...

Comment: for **initWithStyle** when I checked with the debugger it perfectly being called , actually I did aded the content to the cell's contentView with the part of code " [self.contentView addSubview:self.fullNameLabel]; 

for autolayout I think they are set correctly

Comment: Add a line to get the current cell in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`... set a breakpoint... use debug console to check the existence and/or frames of the subviews... Or, use `Debug Hierarchy` to find out where they went.

Comment: ok I did what you told me and I checked if the clicked cell contains its content , and I found them so may be there is a problem with my constraints , I will check them now

Comment: @SAM you can take a snapshot of this then show to us.

Comment: Do the cells have the correct `backgroundColor`, or is that even missing?

Comment: You are not setting any constraints on your image, but twice on `fullNameLabel`.

Comment: @Koen I've deleted the second constraints and leave only constraints for fullNameLabel but still nothing shows up it should at least show me fullNameLabel content . also I've edded a picture of what shows up above if you wanna see

Comment: @aircraft that's what shows up https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYl10.png I've changed the background color to red

Comment: @SAM - when you now debug the view hierarchy, what is it showing for the bounds and/or frame of your fullNameLabel?

Comment: @DonMag when I checked the frame I found 
(lldb) po [selectedCell.fullNameLabel frame]
(origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 0, height = 0))

so here where is the problem

Comment: OK - in your code, it *looks* like you are setting constraints on fullNameLabel relative to contentView, but then immediately setting them relative to itself? Is `updateViewConstraints` actually executing?

Comment: @DonMag I've deleted that part but still don't shows up , and I leaved constraints only for fullNameLabel . you can check my code now

Comment: I'll check now if updateViewConstraints is actually executing

Comment: after adding a breakpoint to the updateViewConstraints it didn't stop !! so there is a problem there !!

Comment: thaaaaaaaank you very much guys it works now , the problem was with updateViewConstraints it wasn't ecuted well :D 
special thanks for you @DonMag

Comment: Is there a reason you separated the logic? I would suggest you use ONE spot in your cell code to Create the subviews + Add the subviews + Set subview constraints... And you should not need to manually call updateConstraints...

Comment: ok mr @DonMag I did what you told me I've used one spot in my cell to Create the subviews + Add the subviews + Set subview constraints . and it works perfectly . thank you very much for your help

Comment: Try setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO for all your views in the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem with the help of guys in comments above , the problem is `the updateViewConstraints` isn't actually executing ! so All I had to do is add after creating my components this to my code in my

> cell.m

```
[self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[self updateViewConstraints];
```

and it's work